# Actionscript 3 dynamic multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array, actionscript

Okay so this is my code

```
var no:int = 0;
        var elem:int = 0;
        loadedData = myLoader.data.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);

        for (var i:int = 0; i < loadedData.length; i++)
        {
            if (loadedData[i] != '')
            {
                if (loadedData[i] != ',')
                {
                    if(patterns[no] == undefined) patterns[no] = [];
                    trace(no);
                    trace(elem);
                    obstacleData[i] = loadedData[i].split(",");
                    trace(patterns[no]);
                    patterns[no][elem]  = obstacleData[i][0];
                    patterns[no][elem + 1]  = obstacleData[i][1];
                    elem += 2;
                    trace('Pattern' , no, ': ', patterns[no]);
                }
                else if (loadedData[i] == ',')
                {
                    no += 1;
                    elem = 0;
                    patterns[no] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is at this line

```
patterns[no][elem]  = obstacleData[i][0];
```

I'm getting the error: [Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property 0 on Number.

I've read around on this and multidimensional arrays just seem to be so much more complicated on AS3 compared to other languages where you just create a multidimensional array and it works.

I feel like I've done something really obvious wrong and will feel like an idiot upon someone telling me but I really need help on this one since I'm new to this whole AS3 way of creating multidimensional arrays.

Just in case the output for the code when run is as so:

```
0
0

Pattern 0 :  300,60
0
2
300,60
Pattern 0 :  300,60,350,90
1
0
0  <--- This might be the problem?
[Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property 0 on        Number.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the error is caused by the line

```
 patterns[no] = 0;
```

I think you want to assign an empty array or maybe null and check for null later.

Comment: That was exactly the problem and I'm just as much of an idiot as I thought I was! Thank you very much, I appreciate it!